# Trying to run a test, but get a fatal error

Tags: php, configuration, phpunit

I configured the external tool correctly. As soon as I start to run a test case I get this error:

```
Failed loading C:\PHP\5.2.13\ext\php_xdebug.dll

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/PHP/5.2.13/ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  require_once(../../../application/cl/Dict.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xxx\abc\abbb\application\cl\DictTest.php on line 5

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../application/cl/Dict.inc' (include_path='.;C:\PHP\5.2.13\pear\') in C:\xxx\abc\abbb\application\cl\DictTest.php on line 5
```

What could it be?

Comment: What it says: PHP could not open `'../../../application/cl/Dict.inc'` from either of these paths: `'.;C:\PHP\5.2.13\pear\'`

Answer (score 1):

I can assure this is due to installation path  problems.
Did you install phpUnit through pear or separately? if you have installed by PEAR, did you set up the PEAR path in php.ini file?

Comment: well, before installing phpunit PEAR asked me if I wanted to add PEAR into the include_path. This is in my php.ini:

include_path=".;C:\PHP\5.2.13\pear\"